# Injecting JavaScript In WebView Android

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, webview, android-webview

I have the following WebView script :

This script load JavaScript and website url, when the application detect the phrase `access_token` it should redirect to another webpage with the data from `access_token`
for example:

- the home page loaded
- the user visted http://example2.com/?access_token=XXX
- the app check the url and redirect user to http://example3.com/?token=XXX

```js
    @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_homepage);
            mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);
            // Enable Javascript
            WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
            webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    
        String javascriptCodeUrl= "javascript:var token = \n"+
        "top.location.href.split('access_token=')[1]; \n"+
        "if (token) { \n"+
        "top.location.href = 'http://example.com/?user=' + token;}";

                    mWebView.loadUrl(javascriptCodeUrl);

            mWebView.loadUrl("http://default-webpage.com");
            // Force links and redirects to open in the WebView instead of in a browser
            mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You monitor the URLs in shouldOverrideURL method. There is no need to use Javascript injections. It can be done in Java.